# I have or I have got?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, sequence-of-tenses

Sometimes I find native speakers use "have got" and other times "have". I want to know what "have got" here is? an auxiliary verb or what?

Comment: The present tense of the verb have has two forms in English: have and have got. They mean exactly 100% the same thing.

Comment: The discussion here is useful as well if you are interested in the past tense of "have got" - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140842/is-the-sentence-tom-said-he-hadnt-got-any-money-reported-speech-from-tom-sai/140845#140845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Have got" isn't an auxiliary verb.  If you regard "have got" as *have* + the past participle *got*, then the *have* portion of *have got* is an auxiliary verb.

*Structurally* and in terms of its history, "have got" can be regarded as a *present perfect* form.  *Semantically*, however it behaves as a *simple present*, as a synonym of "have".

"Got" can be regarded as meaningless in the expression "have got".  (However, occasionally "have got" is used in its full meaning of "have obtained" or "have fetched", at least in BrE.  AmE would prefer "have gotten" in such cases.)

"Have got" is simply a colloquial variant of "have".  The two can be used interchangeably a lot of the time, including when "have" is a main verb:

> He has a television.
>
> He has got a television.

They are also interchangeable in "have to":

> I have to leave now.
>
> I've got to leave now.

However, "have got" cannot replace "have" in cases where "have" is an auxiliary, nor where "have" is being used together with the dummy verb "do":

> I have eaten lunch.
>
> *I have got eaten lunch. (*Doesn't make sense.*)
>
> Do you have a pencil I could borrow?
>
> *Do you have got a pencil I could borrow? (*Doesn't make sense.*)

The interrogative form of "have got" is:

> Have you got a pencil I could borrow?

although we also use

> Do you have a pencil I could borrow?

("Do you got a pencil" is sometimes heard in AmE slang.)

Comment: Excellent explanation thanks but I still want to classify "have got" gramaticaly

Comment: I'm not sure how to say it any more clearly. *Formally* it's a (specialised use of) present perfect (from *get*). *Semantically* and *functionally* it's the simple present, equivalent to *have*. (The full OED says the same; it appears under *get* in a section called "specialized uses of the perfect".) (Cf Latin deponent verbs: passive in form, active in meaning!) In my experience, learners are encouraged to regard it as an alternative form of the *simple present* of *have*. The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language also treats it as such. So there's a lot of support for that view.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know it's American/British preferences both are the same no difference.

Comment: Please support your answer with more details.